cloudwatch: Getting task IDs/logs associated with scheduled ECS task invocations
We have a Lambda function that catches and records container events so that we can maintain a searchable history of invocations. Still, it'd be very useful to identify the task IDs that correspond with when the schedule metrics say that a certain invocation reportedly happened.
For example, I just restarted a schedule (using Terraform to readd one that I had temporarily commented-out). The monitor chart said that one was started but it doesn't appear that one started (or, at least, triggered our container-events Lambda function). Is there really no way to get a list of invocations and timestamps for a particular schedule?
Please don't suggest the short ECS task log, which doesn't associate them with the schedules (because this is a CloudWatch thing).

ECS scheduled tasks are orchestrated by CloudWatch Events (or EventBridge, if using the newer version). When a scheduled task is triggered, an event is emitted in CloudWatch Events. This event contains details like the task ID, invocation time, and the ECS service or cluster associated with it.
You can capture these events to track the task IDs and execution times.
You can set up CloudWatch Event Rule to capture ECS task state changes, specifically for tasks launched by a scheduled event. In the rule, you can match the event pattern for ECS task state changes (RUNNING state) with the scheduled ECS task:
{
  "source": ["aws.ecs"],
  "detail-type": ["ECS Task State Change"],
  "detail": {
    "lastStatus": ["RUNNING"],
    "group": ["service:my-scheduled-task"]  // Replace with your ECS scheduled task group
  }
}

Target your Lambda function with this event rule to capture and log the task ID, timestamp, and any other relevant metadata.

Thank you. As mentioned, this is what we already have. I'm asking if there's anywhere else this information can be found in case there was a Lambda invocation error or runtime issues. Some place that can be queried and is more robust that the short task execution log in ECS.

You can query CloudTrail to track Lambda invocation failures and ECS task invocations. CloudTrail logs API calls, so if there's a failure to trigger the Lambda, it would show up here. This can help you trace whether the issue was due to Lambda not being triggered or ECS tasks failing before the Lambda function could even run.
